# Designing a circuit that outputs variable voltage

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider, output, variable

Total noob here, I'm looking to implement a circuit to control a fan that has these specifications:

- Pin 1 and 3 are DC-
- Pin 2 is DC+
- Voltage should be from 6 to 16 V
- It needs to operate in 70-second cycles

So let's say we're only giving it 6V. For 70 seconds we need to output 6V between pins 1 and 2, then next 70 seconds 6V between pins 3 and 2.

I'm thinking of using simple voltage dividers with resistors for the variable output part, for example 6 resistors and switches for 5 different outputs. Then, using an astable vibrator (relays, capacitors, resistors) for switching the potential from pin 1 to 3.

I'm not sure yet what to use to control the voltage, maybe Arduino but I guess it will come down to switches anyway.

Am I talking nonsense? Is there a right/easier way to do this?

Comment: why do you need voltage dividers?  ... just use a relay for on/off control

Comment: Can you link to a datasheet?

Comment: You can't use voltage dividers for current consuming loads. How much current does the fan actually need?

Comment: ""So let's say we're only giving it 6V. For 70 seconds we need to output 6V between pins 1 and 2, then next 70 seconds 6V between pins 3 and 2."" - Why? If both pins 1 and 3 are "DC-", why change the connection?  Fan manufacturer and part number?  Vendor site?

Comment: @jsotola I need to output variable voltage for different fan speeds, between 6 and 16 volts.

Comment: @Null I don't have anything else except what I described. I don't even know if I have to add a delay between lowering the voltage for pin 1 and increasing for pin 3 or I can switch instantly. I need to switch like this in order to reverse the fan direction, that's how it says it works. It should need 3W. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j5FxY4Wo6gw4Ok6KAnNMFHZTQ-YqcKlu/view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voltage dividers don't work if the circuit is supposed to provide at least some power. Either the output voltages will vary under load, or you won't find suitable/affordable resistors that can take the power they'd need to dissipate.

A clean solution is to use a variable voltage regulator and feed its reference voltage with a potentiometer (or a digital pot or a DAC if you want to control it digitally). Cheap variable voltage regulators exist on beginner-friendly breakout boards and I suggest you try one of those.
If you understand how your model works, you can replace the potentiometer with a resistor ladder and switches if you prefer discrete voltage levels.

Comment: Sounds right, I'll look into that, thanks! And for making the switch from pins 1-2 to 3-2, I can just use some cleverly positioned switches? Considering I'll control everything digitally. Or will I need two regulators?

Comment: @aelveon I would use **one** "cleverly positioned" toggle switch which connects the variable voltage to either pin 1 *or* pin 3. This way you only need one regulator and there is no change that you short any reversed voltage/apply voltage to both P1 & P3, which might fry sth.

Comment: That sounds right, thanks again!